# How to set properly SCALA_HOME in a macport installed scala

Tags: scala, macports

I have installed multiple versions of Scala (2.9 and 2.10) on my mac (OS X 10.7.5) using macports. I like this way because can switch easily between these two versions by the simple "port select" command.
But, the SCALA_HOME environment variable does not get set automatically with this command.

Is there a proper nice macport command to set correctly the SCALA_HOME variable?
If no, what directory should the SCALA_HOME point to in a macport installed scala?

Thanks

EDIT:
Until now the best way I found is with a shell script that looks what is the current scala command and adjust the SCALA_HOME variable accordingly. I run it always after switching the Scala version.

Here is the important command in the script. I'm not an expert shell programmer, therefore I'll be thankful for any suggestion:

`` export SCALA_HOME=$(ls -l `which scala` | gawk 'match($0, "(/opt/local/share/.*)/bin/scala", a) {print a[1]}') ``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, until now the best solution I found is to run following command after changing scala version:

```
export SCALA_HOME=$(ls -l `which scala` | gawk 'match($0, "(/opt/local/share/.*)/bin/scala", a) {print a[1]}')
```

I have included that command also in my `.bash_profile` so my `SCALA_HOME` always points to the scala version I am using currently.

This command uses gawk 4.1.1 installed from MacPorts.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a way to have MacPorts do it for you, but Scala is installed at /opt/local/share/scala-2.10/ for me. So I added

```
export SCALA_HOME="/opt/local/share/scala-2.10/"
```

to my ~/.profile and everything seems to be working for me now (although you'd have to switch change your $SCALA_HOME every time you switch versions).

Comment: thanks for your answer, yes, that's what I have to do manually every time I switch the Scala version. I was looking for something more direct and easy, a command, hopefully supported by MacPorts, but have not found any until now.

Answer (score 0):

Currently when scala is installed via brew it's path set to
/usr/local/Cellar/scala/[version]
So SCALA_HOME could be defined as follows:

```
export SCALA_HOME=$(greadlink -f $(dirname "$(greadlink -f $(which scala))")/../../)
```

p.s: You need to install 'greadlink' for that since the regular readlink doesn't support the 'f' flag.

Answer (score -1):

if you are installing the versions with `home brew` you can simply:

```
brew switch scala 2.10.3
```